# w2ui grid reorderRows to server

Tags: grid, w2ui

I need to send the new row order to the server after re-ordering rows in a w2ui grid, but no event seems to be triggered when dropping a row in a new position.

Any idea of how to trigger an "onRowDrop" event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an undocumented "reorderRow" event type in version 1.5.rc1 that goes along with the "onReorderRow" event in the grid's events.

So problem is solved.